# Provide array[] parameter via Console rather than via Web

Tags: php, arrays, console, command-line-interface, webrequest

In the context of a Web request, PHP can be provided *array* parameters, providing them (via GET or POST) as `param_name[]=foo`, `param_name[sub_element]=foo` or `param_name[sub_element][]=foo`.
This is explained on the [PHP-Manual @ "Variables From External Sources"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

Usually they are provided via `<form>` inputs like `<input type="text" name="my_nested[param]" value="foobar">`; and PHP will automatically create a variable `$my_nested = [ 'param' => 'foobar' ]`.

That's great. But, **how would one achieve the same using the CLI?**
The above link doesn't mention anything.

In the context of a Console request, can PHP natively handle arrays as it does for Web requests?

Something like `php -f myscript -- <my_param_as_a_nested_array> foobar`.

And in negative case, what are common workarounds/solutions?

Comment: If you are running the script through PHP via `exec` or  something then `"php myscript " . http_build_query($array);` and other ways and access like the duplicate.